# Mocking R.string in Mockito

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit, android-resources

Hi I am writing a unit test in which I require to send ID of a string resource. How can I do that using mockito. My test case returns null.

Expected :Signature
Actual   :null

I think the issue is with the usage for R.string. can any one suggest what should I be doing please.
Should I be calling init function as rendererLocaleContext and defaultLocaleContext are not initialised

My string resource

```
<string name="renderer_signature">Signature</string>
```

Function I am writing test case for getString function which is in

```
class StandardRendererUtility @Inject constructor(app: App, private val rendererLocale: String) {
      private val rendererLocaleContext: Context
      private val defaultLocaleContext: Context
      init {
        val configuration = Configuration(app.getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration())
        configuration.setLocale(Locale(rendererLocale))
        rendererLocaleContext = app.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration)
        configuration.setLocale(Locale(DEFAULT_LOCALE))
        defaultLocaleContext = app.getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration)
    }

    fun getString(stringId: Int, numOfColumns: Int): String {
        val localeString = getStringByLocale(stringId)
        if (numOfColumns != NO_OF_COLUMNS_ZERO && rendererLocale != DEFAULT_LOCALE) {
            val maxLength = getMaxLength(numOfColumns)
            val padding = getPaddingLength(numOfColumns)
            return formatString(localeString, maxLength, padding)
        } else {
            return localeString
        }
    }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private fun getStringByLocale(id: Int): String {
        val rendererLocaleString = rendererLocaleContext.getResources().getString(id)
        return if (rendererLocaleString.isEmpty()) {
            defaultLocaleContext.getResources().getString(id)
        } else rendererLocaleString
    }
}
```

My unit test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class StandardRendererUtilityTest {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var standardRendererUtility: StandardRendererUtility

    @Before
    fun setup(){

    }

    @Test
    fun `when noOfColumns are 0 and rendererLocale is en return unformatted string`() {
        assertEquals("Signature", standardRendererUtility.getString(R.string.renderer_signature, 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using resource strings, why don't you just copy the string directly from your resources and use it in your unit test.

Comment: because standardRendererUtility.getString function only accepts string ID but not string

Comment: You can't get android resources in a JUnit test. This is strictly Java only. You can't mock Resources either. You need to architect you code differently.

Comment: @BRDroid Another way to do this is to mock the function - if it's part of a library. Create a fake duplicate of the `standardRendererUtility.getString` function that accepts a string, and use it in your test.